# Display a message to all users before logging in

Tags: windows-7, login

I have a few public access computers.

Is there a way, as soon as someone logs on, to have a popup that shows our policy text with an agree button on the bottom? And refuse to let them log in if they do not agree?

Kind of like how freeware makes you agree before you can install it. I am using Windows 7 Pro

Comment: On domain? Does it have to be post logon?

Comment: A popup when a user logs in in Windows? Why is the question tagged `internet`?

Comment: How can it log you off (if you press cancel) if it asks you 'before logging in' (in the title)?

Comment: @shub I put that in, as otherwise, this question would end up being a software recommendation, which would be closed.

Comment: @CanadianLuke Ah.... I didn't see that you've edited it, you should probably remove the 'and log them off' as well then...

Answer (score 4):

Create a logon banner. It doesn't give them a chance to deny it, but it forces them to see it and agree (by continuing to use the computer).

1a)  If you have a domain, use Group Policy:

Navigate to Computer Configuration | Policies | Windows Settings | Security Settings | Local Policies | Security Options

Look for the policies that start with *Interactive logon:*, specifically:

*"Interactive logon: Message title for users attempting to log on"* and *"Interactive logon: Message text for users attempting to log on"*

1b)  If you don't have a domain setup, then you'll have to edit the registry of each computer:

Under the registry entry: `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\winlogon\`

There you have two String values:

- `LegalNoticeCaption`
- `LegalNoticeText`

2)  Modify the *Caption/Title* choice to something like "Attention!", and modify the *Text* to add your warning message.

3)  If using GP, apply a `gpupdate`.

4)  Reboot the computer to apply the changes.

Example of what you'll end up with:

[image]

Comment: Upvoted anyways, different methods

Comment: @techie007 - The DoD stop using Windows Vista Enterprise in 2013 time to update your screenshots.

Comment: @Ramhound Blame Google Images for not providing me a decent Windows 7 version. ;)

Answer (score 2):

As per [TechRepublic](http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/adding-messages-to-windows-7s-logon-screen/?tag=nl.e102), you can edit the registry to achieve this.

Click Start, type `regedit` and press Enter. You may need to click the **Yes** or **Continue** button on the UAC window.

Navigate to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System` on the left side. On the right side, look for `legalnoticecaption` and `legalnoticetext`. Edit these to display what message you want to appear on the login screen.

Once this has been set, when the user goes to log in, they need to click the [OK] button first.